# Flask API failing to decode JSON data. Error: “message”: “Failed to decode JSON object"

Tags: python, json, flask

I know there are similar questions asked but I can't figure why this doesn't work.

```
 curl -H "content-type: application/json" -d "@test.json" -X POST http://localhost:5000/v1/mod/model/pre
```

And I got the error:

```
"message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1696 (char 1695)"
```

Comment: Cause "@test.json" isn't JSON string

Comment: @GProst so test.json is a json file. how do i use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap `@test.json` in quotes:

```
curl -H "content-type: application/json" -d @test.json -X POST http://localhost:5000/v1/mod/model/pre
```

Comment: the json file is quite long...its not really letting me post here

Comment: Well, judging by the error message it seems like it contains an invalid JSON string

Comment: yeah it is. i edit the json file and its fine now. thank you